# Memory Management with Command Pattern

Tags: c++, memory-management, command-pattern

So, I've got the following Command Pattern implementation, which is contained within a `std::map<CString, IWrite*> commandMap`:

```cpp
class IWrite
{
protected:
   CStdioFile* fileWriter;

public:
   IWrite(CStdioFile* _fileWriter)
      : fileWriter(_fileWriter)
   {
   }

   virtual ~IWrite()
   {
   }

   virtual BOOL exec() = 0;
};
```

```cpp
class FloatWrite : public IWrite
{
private:
   float input;

public:
   FloatWrite(CStdioFile* _fileWriter, float _input)
      : IWrite(_fileWriter), input(_input)
   {      
   }

   BOOL exec()
   {
      CString fieldvalue;
      fieldvalue.Format("%f", input);
      fileWriter->WriteString(fieldvalue);

      return TRUE;
   }
};
```

The issue I'm having is that my static analysis tool complains that `fileWriter` is not freed or zeroed in the destructor of `IWrite`. However, by adding a `delete fileWriter` in the destructor, I get a memory access error when I delete the Command Pattern object in the map before calling `std::map.clear()` as below:

```cpp
// free map memory
for ( std::map<CString, IWrite*>::iterator mapItr = commandMap.begin();
      mapItr != commandMap.end();
      ++mapItr)
{
   delete mapItr->second;
}
commandMap.clear();
```

Am I approaching memory management incorrectly here? I have not done much work with STL maps, so I'm not familiar with an idiomatic approach.

EDIT: How I add elements to the map:

```cpp
void FooClass::initCommandMap(const MSG_DATA_STRUCT * msgdata)
{
   // Write a float, foo
   commandMap[_T("foo")] = new FloatWrite(&fileWriter, msgdata->foo);
   // Write an unsigned int, bar
   commandMap[_T("bar")] = new UIntWrite(&fileWriter, msgdata->bar);
   // etc...
}
```

This is called each time the user chooses to write out the data, so the `fileWriter` object used by the various `exec()`'s is current with the file selected by the user.

Note that `CStdioFile fileWriter` is a member variable of `FooClass`.

Comment: You probably need to apply the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: @n.m. This isn't rule of three (yet...) it's just a case of understanding who's meant to own those objects.

Comment: @Roddy: one leads to the other.

Comment: @n.m. Ok, if I were to do that, would I put the `delete fileWriter` in the destructor of `IWrite`, or `FloatWrite` and its ilk?

Comment: @cjm571 - explain why you are using pointers, and where the objects are created, and how. Chances are you probably shouldn't be using pointers at all...

Comment: @Roddy Yeah, I think that's my problem. I'm not clear on which class is responsible for `fileWriter`

Comment: As IWrite is presumably an interface, it would be fair to say that it is probably not strictly responsible for ownership.

Comment: @cjm571 +1 for the use of a static analysis tool on your code!  More programmers should do this.

Comment: Please show code where you add things to the map.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you keep a pointer to fileWriter? From what I see, your Command object assumes that a writer should exist before the command can be used. It also shouldn't try to manage the writer object, since it can be shared by multiple command objects. 
Try keeping a reference instead.

```
class IWrite
{
protected:
   CStdioFile &fileWriter;

public:
   IWrite(CStdioFile &_fileWriter)
      : fileWriter(_fileWriter)
   {
   }

   virtual ~IWrite()
   {
   }

   virtual BOOL exec() = 0;
};
```

Comment: Isn't this illegal though? `CStdioFile` is a child of `CObject`, which is non-copyable. So the `fileWriter(_fileWriter)` in the initializer list causes a compilation error

Comment: Shouldn't be, at least the following code compiles with g++: http://pastebin.com/dnTqQ7wK . Can you show your code and the error message you're getting?

Comment: @cjm571 That isn't a copy; its a *reference* member. Make sure your member is a reference variable; not a flat instance variable.

Comment: @Grigory When I add `fileWriter = dataIn.fileWriter;`, where `dataIn` is an `IWrite&` parameter in the `operator =` overload, I get an error `C2248: 'CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'` Note that this is after having changed `fileWriter` to be a `CStdioFile &`

Comment: Also, this was the original reason I went with pointers. Since my map values were `IWrite*`, the `operator =` for `IWrite` was never used, and thus `CObject::operator =` was not required either.